# Is this direct link for Office 2019 download legitimate and safe?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2019

Is link below official/legitimate direct download link for Office 2019 professional plus?

https://officecdn.microsoft.com/pr/492350f6-3a01-4f97-b9c0-c7c6ddf67d60/media/en-us/ProPlus2019Retail.img

Comment: microsoft.com is legit as it gets

Answer (score -1):

What I can be sure of is that it is not an official download link.

I do not recommend that you download office software from any unofficial site, which can be a potential hazard.

You can download it from the official link below:

[Download and install or reinstall Microsoft 365 or Office 2019 on a PC or Mac](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/download-and-install-or-reinstall-microsoft-365-or-office-2019-on-a-pc-or-mac-4414eaaf-0478-48be-9c42-23adc4716658?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

Comment: How is microsoft.com an unofficial site?